# Jquery Text After <br> and SubStr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a td

```
<table><tr>
    <td> Monday <br> 11/04/2013 </td>
</tr></table>
```

What i want to acheive is get the date in Javascript. How do i avoid text before BR tag and get date in date in JS format.

Comment: If you know that the date contents will need to be extracted and manipulated at a later stage, why not wrap it in it's own `<span class="date">` element. This will make it **much** easier to find on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the date with that exact markup, use the following...

```
var date = new Date($("td").html().split("<br>")[1]);
```

**[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gcvc2/)**

If the markup changes in any way then that won't work.  You should really consider using a class to identify the date column.

Answer (score 4):

To read the text, try

```
var text = $.trim($($('table td br')[0].nextSibling).text())
```

To convert this to date format, either use a library like momentjs or do it yourself using a .split() and creating date using date, month and year parts

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8Jbh/)

Comment: Never thought of using a `<br>` in a selector... interesting!

Comment: No need to drop the `.nextSibling` text node in a jQuery object just to get its text. Thats too much jQuery IMO.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue):

```
var text = $('table br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue
alert($.trim(text));  //  11/04/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Lkbjh/)

```
var date = new Date($("td").html().match(/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}/g));
alert(date);
```

Note: it will work only for `dd/mm/yyyy` format

Comment: It would be great to mention here that your regex is dependent on the format of the date.